# Select only waiting jobs under consideration of maximum running jobs

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL database table as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `TIMERS` (
  `id` int(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `StateId` int(3) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `Job` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`,`StateId`)
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
INSERT INTO `TIMERS` (`id`, `StateId`, `Job`) VALUES
  ('1', '1', 'waiting job'),
  ('2', '1', 'waiting job'),
  ('3', '2', 'running job'),
  ('4', '3', 'error job'),
  ('5', '2', 'running job'),
  ('6', '4', 'other job'),
  ('7', '1', 'waiting job'),
  ('8', '1', 'waiting job'),
  ('9', '1', 'waiting job'),
  ('10', '1', 'waiting job'),
  ('11', '1', 'waiting job'),
  ('12', '1', 'waiting job'),
  ('13', '1', 'waiting job'),
  ('14', '1', 'waiting job'),
  ('15', '1', 'waiting job'),
  ('16', '1', 'waiting job'),
  ('17', '1', 'waiting job'),
  ('18', '1', 'waiting job');
```

The table is for job executions, and the process to search new jobs (a bash script) runs every minute as cronjob.

`StateId 1` = waiting jobs, `StateId 2` = running jobs

My problem is, I will execute maximum AND minimum 5 jobs at same time as running.

As example (Bash script via cron every minute)

- 3 Jobs has StateId 2 (running), now I will select only the next 2 waiting jobs (max 5).
- 0 Jobs has StateId 2 (running), now I will select next 5 waiting jobs (max 5).

Any idea how I can do that in a single MySQL SELECT statement ?

I have tried with `SELECT (SUM(..))`, `IF CASE`, ect., but I have no idea how I can say in the SQL Statement: IF x jobs running, SELECT me the next ( 5 - x ) waiting jobs. I have no idea how I would start there.

Example: [FIDDLE](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/rwADHotaESSaNnQ5CWpgXJ/0)

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Thanks for information. I have add a fiddle example.
https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/rwADHotaESSaNnQ5CWpgXJ/0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will 1. select 5 jobs ordered by StateId desc (running jobs first), 2. filter only StateId = 1, effectively selecting up to 5 waiting jobs minus running jobs.

```sql
select * from
  (select * from jobs order by StateId desc limit 5) sub
  where StateId = 1;
```

[See the fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=a714305f62d4ac210dca446a7d0c79de)

Comment: That not work. it exist items with StateId 3,4,5,... also. If i set `by StateId ASC` i get every 5 result. But currently 3 items are set as StateId 2 (running).

Comment: Then se subquery should have `where StateId in (1,2)`, [see here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/abnCUFLLgJS5JPZAw45mfX/0)

Comment: Thats the correct answer. Work as expected. +1. Thanks.

Comment: Glad it works :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT *
FROM ( SELECT *
       FROM jobs_tables
       ORDER BY StateId = 1 /* , CreatedAt ASC */
       LIMIT 5 ) subquery
WHERE StateId = 1
```

will select 0 to 5 waiting jobs, depends on the amount of running jobs.

Uncomment for to select oldest jobs.

[sample fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=9bd772a382ca46f5e32de237c7497246)

Comment: Get every empty result.

Comment: @TheAlphaGhost This means that there are 5 or more running jobs.

Comment: Provide the same as a fiddle. with source table and sample data.

Comment: @TheAlphaGhost Show the output for `SELECT DISTINCT StateId FROM TIMERS;`. It seems that you have the values out of (1,2).

Comment: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/rwADHotaESSaNnQ5CWpgXJ/0

Comment: I update your fiddle [link](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=bd20783a4d3af35620bee01c042ceccf)

Comment: @TheAlphaGhost You have not said that another values except 1 and 2 are present. Simply add `WHERE StateId IN (1, 2)` into the subquery. [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=f0ae246fffa144844bf1e91510c175c0).